# What do these weird characters mean?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, symbols, block

I'm reading a Ruby book but it doesn't explain the following:

1. What is this: `validates :name,  :presence => true`

   - I mean I know what it does but what's `validates`? Is it a method of the validator class? If so, how come it's called without mentioning the class name first?
   - What's the meaning of `:` in the previous code and in Rails on general?
2. In the following code: `<%= form_for([@post, @post.comments.build]) do |f| %>`

   - Is `form_for` an object or a procedural function?
   - What's the meaning of the `|` character in `|f|`
3. In `<%= link_to 'Edit Post', edit_post_path(@post) %>`

   - Who, where and when was `edit_post_path` method defined?
   - To which class it belongs?

Comment: Mr. Neighborly’s Humble Little Ruby Book

Comment: These questions are answered in [Rails 3 in Action](http://manning.com/katz), it's a beginner -> intermediate book for Rails 3. Should bring you up to speed on these things.

Comment: @emurad Mmmmmm it quickly scanned through it, and does not at all mention the concept of a `symbol` in ruby. If you want to learn ruby, i recommend "The Wellgrounded Rubyist", and to learn rails "Agile Webdevelopment with Rails". These are the best imho to get you started.

Comment: Thank Ryan and nathanvda, I'll look into these resources too.

Comment: @Ryan Bigg: Flagged as spam! :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

1. `validates` is a method, part of the [validators](http://thelucid.com/2010/01/08/sexy-validation-in-edge-rails-rails-3) in Rails. It is declared in (actually, included to) a superclass, that is why it does not have to be declared in the model. The `:` in front of anything signifies a symbol, not a variable. Symbols are part of Ruby, somewhat similar to strings.
2. `form_for` is a method, which takes a number of parameters and a block (that is why there is a `do` afterwards). The `|` is part of Ruby syntax, the way you enclose code block parameters.
3. `edit_post_path` is defined by the *Rails magic* and the routes. It is a helper method.

I encourage you to read [this book](http://www.ruby-doc.org/docs/ProgrammingRuby) about Ruby to get more familiar with symbols, code blocks, modules and other things that make Ruby a great programming language.

Comment: Thanks for the book recommendation. I'll read it after I'm done with the current one.